# Storing File Path as variable for C# Console Application

Tags: c#, console-application, appsettings

I'm trying to create a C# console application that will generate a log file. I'd like to have some flexibility with where the log file will be stored.

I tried using the Settings.settings file with:

Name: logDrive
Type: string
Scope: Application
Value: C:\Scripts\Logs

In my code, I'm using:

```
string logFile = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
logFile = logFile.Replace(@"/", @"-").Replace(@"\", @"-") + ".log";
string logDrive = Properties.Settings.Default.logDrive;
StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter(logDrive + logFile);
```

When compiling the above I get the error message "The given path's format is not support."

If it helps, the values for:

logDrive = "C:\Scripts\ServiceDesk\Logs"
logFile = "3-23-2009 1:20 PM.log"

Does anyone have any thoughts/ recommendations for a better approach and/ or what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't include a `:` in a filename.  A better approach might be to use a format like

```
YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS.log
```

(e.g. `20090323_231245.log`)

This has the benefit of being easily sortable, and it doesn't use any invalid characters.

You can get this using

```
string logFile = string.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}.log", DateTime.Now);
```

**Notes:**

Also, as suggested in the comments, you should consider using `Path.Combine` to combine your directory and filename.  This will help mitigate issues with trailing path separators, etc.

Comment: +1.  I name my log files in a similar way so they can be sorted.

Comment: You should also be using System.IO.Path.Combine(logDrive, logFile) instead of manually concatenating them ;)

Comment: @Tracker1: I think you'v reversed minutes and the month

Comment: @ck, @Daniel L Thank you, I ended up using: 

string logFile = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");

Comment: @womp Thank you for the System.IO.Path.Combine tip. I had not heard of this, so did some reading and have started using it. If anyone else cares, check out http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/04/systemiopath.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll also need to add a trailing slash to your 'logDrive'. I.e:

```
logDrive = "C:\Scripts\ServiceDesk\Logs\"
```

..or use Path.Combine as suggested in the other answer

Comment: Thank you for catching this. I added the trailing slash.